# How can I add a MyDrawPanel to a program while adding other objects as well?

Tags: user-interface, swing, graphics, jpanel

I am attempting to make a simple game, and I have loaded an image onto a myDrawPanel, which is on the JFrame, successfully. However, I also want to add other things to my GUI, such as buttons, etc. I cannot do this, however, because when I add the myDrawPanel to a JPanel, all I get is a small square in the top center of the window. This is proving to be greatly limiting, and I was wondering if there is an alternative "JObject" that I can add the myDrawPanel to in order to allow for the customization of my GUI. Thanks in advance, and Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 2):

A JPanel (or sub-class) generally obtains its size from the components it contains.  If no components are in it, it will be small.

One way to fix that is to call setPreferredSize(Dimension) on the customized panel.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm new to Java so I'm not quite sure how to approach this. Can you tell me the command I would use if the myDrawPanel holds an image that is 1100x800, and the JPanel is called "p1"? Thanks again for the help.

Comment: I already told you the method you could use so I cannot see how to make it simpler other than to come over to your house and type it directly into your computer.  I won't be doing that.  OTOH if you post an SSCCE (http://pscode.org/sscce.html) of your current code, you are likely to get better help.  Note that an SSCCE is a very specific form of code, please read the link before posting code you think is an SSCCE.

Answer (score 1):

p1.setPreferredSize(new Dimention(1100,800));